# Effecient way to parse pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe which contains the following columns:

```
    feat      norm    window  type  user_id
   ----------------------------------------
0   all    0.110000     0    true   user1
1  all1    0.232110     0    null   user2
2  all2    0.324234     0    true   user3
3   all    0.323120     0    null   user4
4   all    0.322000     1    true   user1
5  all1    0.100000     1    null   user1
6  all1    0.200000     1    null   user2
7  all2    0.300000     1    true   user3
```

I need to make a result dataframe that contains :

```
feat      user       result_norm
--------------------------------
all    user1_true      -0.212
all1   user2_null      0.03211
all2   user3_true      0.0324
all    user4_null      0.323120
```

Note : user4 entry is in output, since its window is 0 and respective '1' entry is not in dataframe. It is as good as subtraction window 0 norm with 0 value.

i.e. for every user, type and feature I need to subtract norms and make a new dataframe. We get the above shown result table by subtracting
(user1,true,all,0) norm with (user1,true,all,1) norm. Basically per user, per type, per feat get difference of norms between the windows. It is not necessary that all user,type, feat combination has its opposite window entry to subtract from, in this case if window is 0, we copy the row to output dataframe or else discard it.

I have currently achieved by doing :

```
data = data.groupby(by=['user_id', 'feat', 'type'])
```

and iterating on each groups using for loop like this :

```
for tuple, group in data:
     #perform operations on this group
```

Though this solution works, it is extremely slow since groupby is expensive operation. The dataframe I have contains about 9000000 entries. Any way to improve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need substract `0` window with `1` window use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) first and then [`sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sub.html):

```
 data = data.set_index(['user_id', 'feat', 'type', 'window'])['norm'].unstack().fillna({1:0})

print (data)
window                    0      1
user_id feat type                 
user1   all  true  0.110000  0.322
        all1 null       NaN  0.100
user2   all1 null  0.232110  0.200
user3   all2 true  0.324234  0.300
user4   all  null  0.323120  0.000

df = data[0].sub(data[1]).reset_index(name='result_norm')
print (df)
  user_id  feat  type  result_norm
0   user1   all  true    -0.212000
1   user1  all1  null          NaN
2   user2  all1  null     0.032110
3   user3  all2  true     0.024234
4   user4   all  null     0.323120
```

Comment: Awesome, it almost does the job but user1,all1, null entry is not supposed to be there. Meaning if we don't have window 0 entry for that, then we neglect that. Any idea on how this would perform on such big data ?

Comment: The first step is remove `null` rows by `data = data[data['type'] != 'null']`

Comment: I think I did not convey it properly. I meant if the dataframe does not have an entry for (user,type,feat) combination then we keep this row only if window is 0. e.g. here (user4, null,all) is supposed to be in the result dataframe since its window is 0. So basically we need to do 0 window - 1 window and if 1 window entry is not there in dataframe then we just take 0 window

Comment: OK, and what about `user3   all2 true`, there is only 1 and no 0 window? What is result? `NaN` or `0.3` or `-0.3` ?

Comment: I have edited, user3 has both. But yea incase if we have only 1 window like u said then it should be NAN which can be filtered later.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much, let me run this on my huge data and check speed once.

Comment: It hardly took any time, @Jezrael you are awesome, thanks a lot again :)

Comment: You are welcome! And you can also upvote, thanks. :)